# How to get attibute and values in xml parsing in android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have a xml file having a format of

```
<question_choices>
<question id="499">What do you call a chicken with bad sunburn</question>
<choices1 id="2231">Burned Chicken</choices1>
<choices2 id="2230">Fried Chicken</choices2>
<choices3 id="2232">Dead Chicken</choices3>
<choices_answer>Fried Chicken</choices_answer>
</question_choices>
```

I have to get both the id and the value during parsing.Also I have set these options in 3 different buttons.So when I click these choice I have to get the value and corresponding id also have to be saved.I tried to use getAttributes() but I dont know where and how to use.So it was not successful.

```
    final XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
    final NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_QUESTION);         
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
         for(int j=0;j<nl.getLength();j++)
         {
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(j);
            listnew[j]=parser.getValue(e,KEY_QUEST); 
            options1[j]= parser.getValue(e, KEY_CHOICE1);
                        options2[j]= parser.getValue(e, KEY_CHOICE2);
                        options3[j]= parser.getValue(e, KEY_CHOICE3);
        }
      TextView question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
      question.setText(listnew[x]);

      opt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opt1);
      opt1.setText(options1[x]);
      opt1.setOnClickListener(myOptionOnClickListener);

      opt2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opt2);
      opt2.setText(options2[x]);
      opt2.setOnClickListener(myOptionOnClickListener);

      opt3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opt3);
      opt3.setText(options3[x]);
      opt3.setOnClickListener(myOptionOnClickListener);

      x++; 
     }
```

I'm using a DOM parser for parsing.The option what is clicked have to be saved.How should I do this?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138754/getting-an-attribute-value-in-xml-element

Comment: [See this](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-xml-parsing-using-dom-parser.html)

Comment: I'm getting the values in the xml.I need to get the id such as 499.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
 String idQuestion = doc.getElementsByTagName("question").item(0)
                      .getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue();
 String idChoise1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("choices1 ").item(0)
                      .getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue();
 ...
```