# Read xml using XmlPullParser

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

I've the following xml file inside the /mnt/sdcard. I want to get the version of the `item type=provider` from the following file. The file is big(1500 lines) which has other types also. This is simplified file. In the file I'm interested in this node:

```
<Item Type="Provider" Version="19.0.0.0"Checksum="EShHVeNtW1xTfEvLvATwqA==" FileSize="2746200" />
```

From this node I want to get the version i.e. 19.0.0.0.

Here is my xml file:

```
<Manifest guid="FD29E1EF-A5C4-4D19-ACC8-8C98C7E91B02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" PackageType="Full" Scope="APPROVED">
   <Items>
        <Item id="fcxm-8ikj-olk-ffgcxh3" Checksum="EShHVeNtW1xTfEvLvATwqA==" value="f425921f-b6ef-4e58-8a14-fcbd0d7e50e9" />
        <Item Type="question" Version="19.0.0.0"Checksum="EShHVeNtW1xTfEvLvATwqA==" FileSize="2746200" />
        <Item Type="Provider" Version="19.0.0.0"Checksum="EShHVeNtW1xTfEvLvATwqA==" FileSize="2746200" />
    </Items>
</Manifest>
```

I searched on the internet, I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138754/getting-an-attribute-value-in-xml-element) which is iterating to all the nodes of item type. I dont want want to iterate.

How can I do this in Android using `XmlPullParser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can try this,

```
private void parseContent(XmlPullParser parser) 
    throws XmlPullParserException,IOException,Exception {
    int eventType;
    while((eventType=parser.next()) != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG,"Parsing Attributes for ["+parser.getName()+"]");
            Map<String,String> attributes = getAttributes(parser);
        }
        else if(eventType==...);
        else {
            throw new Exception("Invalid tag at content parse");
        }
    }
}

private Map<String,String>  getAttributes(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception {
    Map<String,String> attrs=null;
    int acount=parser.getAttributeCount();
    if(acount != -1) {
        Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG,"Attributes for ["+parser.getName()+"]");
        attrs = new HashMap<String,String>(acount);
        for(int x=0;x<acount;x++) {
            Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG,"\t["+parser.getAttributeName(x)+"]=" +
                    "["+parser.getAttributeValue(x)+"]");
            attrs.put(parser.getAttributeName(x), parser.getAttributeValue(x));
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("Required entity attributes missing");
    }
    return attrs;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, can u please explain what is going on. I dont want to iterate all the items because my xml has 1500+ items of the name 'item`.

Comment: You can not get attribute without iterating. Because parser have to get tag firstly then can reach tags attribute.

Comment: maybe you think about reading xml line by line. And put it to temp file by sorting line which contains "provider". Then you can use this temp xml to parse