# Read xsl uri from xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to read XSL uri from XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl_uri"?>
<Document>
         ...
</Document>
```

I am using org.w3c.dom.Document. Is there any way to get that uri?

Comment: take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138754/getting-an-attribute-value-in-xml-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no DOM method to do it: you'll have to read the processing instruction as text, and parse the pseudo-attributes within the processing instruction "by hand".

However, depending on why you want the information and what you want to do with it, you may be able to use

```
TransformerFactory.getAssociatedStylesheet()
```