# how to pharse XML in java from Java Rest Service Response

Tags: java, web-services

[image]

how can i capture the status and message tags  from this xml response

Comment: https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/java-ee/producing-and-consuming-json-or-xml-in-java-rest-services-with-jersey-and-jackson

Comment: Here is what you need : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138754/getting-an-attribute-value-in-xml-element

Comment: but iam getting error: Premature end of file. XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/)

In Spring 3, one of the feature of `mvc:annotation-driven`, is support for convert object to/from **`XML`** file, if `JAXB` is in project classpath.

Here [SpringGuide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/oxm.html) for marshalling and demarshalling object to xml and vice versa.