# How to read HTML attribute value in java?

Tags: java, html

My question is just very similar to this question
[Getting an attribute value in xml element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138754/getting-an-attribute-value-in-xml-element)

But the file is in Html not xml. The first answer given works for xml file but not html.

```
<form action="action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="fistname" value="Mickey" />
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse" />
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have to read values inside name attribute. Thanks in advance. This question is different from the link or any other asked on StackOverflow. I have checked.

Comment: What framework are you using? How does you Java application consume the html?

Comment: Use an HTML parser, e.g. [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) seems popular.

Comment: I am working on this in purely java. I have a file, I am reading from it via FileInput.

Comment: What works with xml will also work with html in this case. What have you tried and where did the answer to that question fail you?

Comment: @f1sh You seem to be assuming that the HTML is XML compliant.

Comment: @Andreas that's true, I do. But all questions that say "i tried this answer, it didnt work" smells like "i copied it and it didnt run on the first try".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a HTML parser like [`jsoup`](https://jsoup.org/) with the appropriate [`CSS selector`](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax), then get the attribute with [`attr(attributeKey)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#attr-java.lang.String-).

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

...
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
for (Element input : doc.select("input")){
    System.out.println(input.attr("name"));
}
```

**Output:**

```
fistname
lastname
```

You can download it from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.9.2).

Comment: I have never worked with JSoup before. You ran that code??

Comment: your answer is good enough but i have to typecast the doc , Element , etc. And then I am getting error in eclipse.

Comment: you have only one jar to import into your project with is [this](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.9.2/jsoup-1.9.2.jar)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSoup to parse Html elements in java. 
Using Document you can parse html or you can even convert HTML type into string .

Like

```
Document doc = 

    Jsoup.connect("http://www.javatpoint.com").get();  
                    String title = doc.title();  
                    System.out.println("title is: " + title);
```

As you said u arenew to jSoup link to it website here you will find documentation on it

[JSoup](https://jsoup.org)